# How are recommended champions determined?

Tags: league-of-legends

Looking at my profile page and the list of Champions, I can see that I can sort them by several characteristics, including `pusher`, `ranged`, etc. However, they also have the option to sort them by `recommended`. All of the recommended champions for me at the moment are Easy to Medium difficulty. That's the only real pattern of commonality I see.

- Are these recommendations tailored to my current Summoner level (which is only 2) or does the game just automatically recommend champions of lower difficulty?
- Will these recommendations change over time?
- If they do change, what factors affect how the game recommends champions to you? For example, tailoring to my preferences as I play more champions, recommending different difficulties based on K/D ratio, etc.

Comment: I remember seeing Champions marked as Recommended on the LoL web site.  This makes me doubt that they're chosen based on any user-specific data or preferences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recommended champions are the same for every one, regardless of level. They do not change to reflect any of your stats. The champions chosen as 'recommended' are those whose skills are more straight forward than others.

Annie for instance is a burst mage with no utility (besides her passive). Warrwick's auto attacks give him life, as well as one of his spells making him the safest jungler.

In general there is no easy to kill champions in the recommended tab that don't have some sort of escape, excluding maybe Sona or Soraka who are support characters.

Answer (score 1):

*Recommended champions* all have low difficulty scores and are considered good starting candidates for new players. Difficulty is an aggregate score that takes into account the technical skills needed by the player to use the champion's abilities efficiently, the survivability of the champion, and its ability to deal damage.